# Increasing the performance of the or query in match in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation

I am trying to retrieve messages between two users with a query like the one below in my chats collection that I keep in Mongodb, but it works for as long as 10 seconds for users with a high number of messages. I have stated the query and the indexes I added below. Can I fill this query with a new index or get the same result by using something different instead of or?

```
db.chats.explain("executionStats").aggregate([{"$match": {"$or": [{"fromid": "******************", "deleted1": false},{"toid": "******************", "deleted2": false},],},}]);
```

indexes I use;

```
"indexName" : "fromid_1_deleted1_1"
"indexName" : "toid_1_deleted2_1",
```

entire query;

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                { "fromid": userID },
                { "toid": userID }
            ],
            "deleted1": false,
            "deleted2": false
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { "createdat": -1 }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "fromid": 1,
            "toid": 1,
            "createdat": 1,
            "dateseen": 1,
            "msg": 1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                $cond: {
                    if: { $eq: ["$fromid", userID] },
                    then: "$toid",
                    else: "$fromid"
                }
            },
            lastMessage: { $first: "$$ROOT" },
            unreadCount: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [
                        {
                            $and: [
                                { $ne: ["$fromid", userID] },
                                { $eq: ["$dateseen", null] }
                            ]
                        },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects: ["$lastMessage", { "unSeenMsgCount": "$unreadCount" }]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { "createdat": -1 }
    },
    {
        $skip: offset
    },
    {
        $limit: limit
    }
])
```

Comment: Is the index used? Check the explain plan.

Comment: Yes, it is used, the indexes I wrote in the question content are used. fromid_1_deleted1_1 and  toid_1_deleted2_1

Comment: I think then there is not much you can do, apart from using bigger hardware or even a sharded cluster. What means "a high number of messages"?

Comment: Actually, my query works very fast, but some users have messages exceeding 200 thousand. For these users, the delay time reaches 6-8 seconds. Actually, isn't a more optimal solution possible for only 20 million data without using bigger hardware or even a sharded cluster?

Comment: It just takes some time to read 200k documents and send it to the client. Try to add an `$out` stage, I guess it runs much faster - in this case the query itself is not the bottleneck, it would be rather the connection.

Comment: Can you give some more examples? How can I use $out?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the messages sent between the two users? Without knowing the schema, the query seems to retrieve all messages where a specific user is contained in `from` or `to`. Can you apply some form of paging so that you read only a part of the documents at once?

Comment: My purpose is to actually get the last chats of the user with x id and the number of unread messages. But during the match phase, data arrives late. I added the entire query to the question. @Markus

Comment: Do you have an index on createdat field ? the sort operation is heavy if not

Comment: Simply `{$out: "dummyCollection"}` - it must be the last stage in an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Yes, there is, but it does not use this index when I look at the plan. @Fourchette

Comment: Try to add the `createdat` field to `fromid_1_deleted1_1` and `toid_1_deleted2_1` index

Comment: Maybe try `lastMessage: { $top: { sortBy: { createdat: -1 }, output: "$$ROOT" } }` instead of `{ $sort: { createdat: -1 } }` and `lastMessage: { $first: "$$ROOT" }`

Comment: indexes already fromid_1_deleted1_1ve toid_1_deleted2_1. I tried the last thing you said, but unfortunately the query time due to match did not decrease. @WernfriedDomscheit